# C++ Multithreading (Windows implementation of multithreading)

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I recently got back to c++ and started learning multithreading. I have a small program that lists files from a path and for each file that is not a directory it adds them to the list. Next i create as many threads as my number of CPU and when an element is added to the list one of the threads calculates the MD5. Below is my implementation, but is not fully working and I want to understand why:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION critical_section;
std::vector<std::wstring> file_array;
HANDLE thSemaphore;
HANDLE mutex;
int numCPU;
int i = 0;
MD5 md5;

void listFiles(LPCWSTR file){
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file_name;
    wstring convert(file);
    wstring temp = convert + L"\\*";
    LPCWSTR temp_address = temp.c_str();
    HANDLE folder_handle = FindFirstFile(temp_address, &file_name);
    do{
        if (wcscmp(file_name.cFileName, L".") != 0){
            if (wcscmp(file_name.cFileName, L"..") != 0){
                if (file_name.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY){
                }else{
                    wstring convert_folder(file);
                    wstring temp_folder = convert_folder + L"\\" + file_name.cFileName;
                    LPCWSTR file_path = temp_folder.c_str();
                    WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);
                    file_array.push_back(file_path);
                    ReleaseMutex(mutex);
                    ReleaseSemaphore(thSemaphore, 1, NULL);
                }
            }
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(folder_handle, &file_name) != 0);

}


void CalcHash(LPCWSTR file){
    char buffer[1000];
    wcstombs(buffer, file,1000);
    cout << md5.digestFile(buffer)<<"  "<<endl;   //for some reason all the threads stay here without printing until the listfiles function finished.

}

DWORD WINAPI CalcMD5(LPVOID param){
            WaitForSingleObject(thSemaphore, INFINITE);
            if (file_array.size() != 0){
                EnterCriticalSection(&critical_section);
                LPCWSTR file_path = file_array.at(i).c_str();
                i++;
                LeaveCriticalSection(&critical_section);
                CalcHash(file_path);
            }

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo;
    HANDLE threads[13];
    DWORD dwThread[13];
    GetSystemInfo(&sysinfo);
    numCPU = sysinfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
    LPCWSTR input_file;
    wstring input;
    cout << "Introduceti calea fisierului care trebuie copiat: " << endl;
    wcin >> input;
    input_file = input.c_str();
    mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    thSemaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 1000, NULL);
    InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&critical_section, 0x1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < numCPU; i++){
        threads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, CalcMD5, NULL, 0, &dwThread[i]);
    }
    listFiles(input_file);

    WaitForMultipleObjects(numCPU, threads, TRUE, INFINITE);
    DeleteCriticalSection(&critical_section);
    for (int i = 0; i < numCPU; i++){
        CloseHandle(threads[i]);
    }
    CloseHandle(mutex);
    cout << numCPU;

    return 0;
}
```

1. Why every thread waits on the cout from the CalcHash function until listFiles function finished?
2. Does the file_path gets overridden causing the weird printing?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Use the standard c++ multithreading facilities.

Comment: *What* "weird printing"? For some specified input, what is the expected and actual output? And if you haven done it yet, please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is not C++ multithreading. this is Windows specific multithreading. The title is misleading.

Comment: `EnterCriticalSection(&critical_section);LPCWSTR file_path = file_array.at(i).c_str(); i++;LeaveCriticalSection(&critical_section);` -- The gigantic flaw in this -- what if `at()` throws an exception?  You never unlock the critical section.  Don't write synchronization methods this way -- use RAII.

Comment: I intend to use the Windows specific multithreading, therefore the standard c++ multithreading is not an obtion (sorry for the title, i didn't realize). By weird printing i meant everytime i get a different result. I have done it, but the way i done it the first time wasn't really following the parallelism (i was waiting for the list to get populated, then i was calculating md5). By using LeaveCriticalSection i don't unlock the critical section?

Comment: your `WaitForSingleObject(mutex` and `ReleaseMutex(mutex)` absolute senseless. you not synchronize access to `file_array` between writer(`listFiles`) and readers (`CalcMD5`).

Comment: You need to read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx). It's essentially telling you to not call `CreateThread`. @πάνταῥεῖ: Using standard C++ does not help answer the questions asked. The very same questions would be asked.

Comment: @Nerozx -- You don't need to know multithreading to realize that the `LeaveCrititcalSection` call will be totally bypassed if an exception is thrown, no different if you had called `new[]` and an exception bypasses the `delete[]` call.  In C++, [RAII techniques](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) are used.  The link talks about standard C++ multithread functions, but the same applies to Windows functions.

Comment: @Nerozx Also, to answer your question in general, yes, you have a dilemma since the critical section is locked due to not having the `LeaveCriticalSection` call never invoked.  The same can be said in general for the mutex code also.  A `vector::push_back` can throw an exception, thus the `ReleaseMutex` call never gets invoked -- now you've got a locked mutex that can never be unlocked.